# Getting started with LAMP web application using Vista notebook

Tags: lamp

For my personal development, I want to learn web application development on the LAMP stack. (Previously I have done web applications on Windows, using ASP.NET, RIA Services and Silverlight front end.)

I want to do this on my home computer, which is a laptop running Vista.

I am grateful for any advice on how to do this best.

Which LINUX system, and how to run it on my Notebook?

- Ubuntu? desktop or server?
- dual boot mit Ubuntu
- run Ubuntu in a virtual machine
- run ubuntu as a windows application in Vista (e.g. with portable ubuntu)

Which IDE can I use for development?

- Can I do everything using Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Ubuntu server on my machine, in a separate partition to my Vista installation. It works fine - in fact I rarely boot into Windows anymore. Ubuntu runs much quicker - even my wife prefers it!

It's a bit of a leaning curve using a LINUX desktop - but that's what I wanted anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you like to stick with your well known MS OS, then ubuntu server as virtual machine e.g. via VirtualBox or Virtual PC (workaround for ubuntu possible) are a quite nice solutions. This way you can easily copy the VM from one PC to another or give a current state of the VM to another developer/client. The performance is good (providing enough RAM...).

<.repeat>If you like to stick with your well known<./repeat> IDE, then Eclipse is a good choice. PHP Development works great with it. You could also checkout NetBeans.

Comment: I can't remember if my notebook has 1 or 2GB RAM - but from what I read on the this web site: http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/virtualbox either should be enough to run Ubuntu in VirtualBox.

Comment: It will run on such a config, but the pretty fluent development experience will suffer with a low CPU/RAM config. Just give it a try...